# Как не попадать в библиотеку <iostream> при отладке программы ( Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, library

в один момент, при отладке программы, нажимая f11, попадаю в библиотеку iostream. как сделать так, что туда не попадать при обычной отладке..

Comment: Нажмите в этом месте f10 (Шаг с обходом) вместо f11 (Шаг с заходом)

Comment: эээ я решил проблему выбрав -Debug вместо -Release